# How do I navigate to other page with respective data on ng-click of a row table

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a view lets assume `index.cshtml` which is getting data using a service and showing in a table for which each row is clickable. And after I click on a row it should navigate to other page lets call it `details.html` with respective information of particular row.

```
`<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover table-responsive">
            <thead>
                <tr class="bg-primary">
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Role</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody ng-repeat="user in Users">
                <tr ng-click="GetUser(Users,user.userLoginID)" style="cursor:pointer" >
                    <td>{{ user.userLoginID }}</td>
                    <td>{{ user.userName }}</td>
                    <td>{{ user.descOfUser }}</td>
                    <td>{{ user.userRole }}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>`
```

The problem I'm facing is how do I get to navigate to other page with data of row. I tried using `query string` but for query string my angular stops working on that page. Please tell if I have to use `angular-route` then how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the your code like below, and make link for get details,

```
<tbody>
 <tr ng-repeat="user in Users">
                <td>{{ user.userLoginID }}</td>
                <td>{{ user.userName }}</td>
                <td>{{ user.descOfUser }}</td>
                <td>{{ user.userRole }}</td>
                <td><a href="#/user-details/{{user.userLoginID }}" class="btn">&nbsp;<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>&nbsp; details</td>
            </tr>
```

after that create a route for details.html page,

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',
 function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.
  when('/', {
    templateUrl: '/users.html',
    controller: 'listCtrl'
  })
  .when('/user-details/:userLoginId', {
    templateUrl: '/details.html',
    controller: 'detailsCtrl', // this is new controller name
   })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });
}]);
```

Now created the route with **userId** as **routeParameter** to get the details of particular user.

Then create a controller for get and show the details of particular user,

```
app.controller('detailsCtrl', function ($scope, $location, $routeParams) {
   // call service to get details  
  // get the user id like this "$routeParams.userLoginId"
});
```

Finally, display the details in details.html page.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it is: The data should be referenced in the controller or service, your ng-click should be a link instead. Like `<a ng-href="/user/{{userLoginID}}">details</a>`.

In your routes you create a parameterized route, like `user/:id` and use [$routeParams](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams) in your new controller  to know which user is the visitor looking for and pass that id to your service to get the right information.

If you wanna do it literally how you're asking, you can pass that information as  a get parameter to your new route but it will be a lot messier and insecure.

Comment: Okay, you mean to say that `<tr>` should be a link rather than a `js function call` ?

Comment: Yes, tr can't be a link, so you would have to modify the markup, or add an anchor inside some or all td.

Comment: This is an example of how to configure the route https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#example

Comment: Earlier I was doing this way. `<td><a ng-href="path?UserId ={{user.userLoginID}}">{{ user.userRole }}</a></td>` and it navigated to next page but angular stopped working there. Should I use onload function to get query parameter and call the filter for data

Comment: There are many things that could be missing, it would depend on how your routes and controllers are structured, maybe if you post that I can see, or you can go back to the start and make sure your routes are working fine. Any error in the console, or just stops working?